# append html to <head> with JQuery

Tags: jquery

My situation is that, I have page contains a button and some links. Whenever user click on the button, it tries to append tag `<base>` to `<head>`

```
function avoidRediect(){
    $('head').append('<base target="_blank" />');
}
```

But the page does not take the effect(means the link is still opened in the same window).
Is my way correct?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this should work.

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/YjC6y/37/

If you remove the Javascript line it will open in the same frame.

What browser do you use there?

Comment: Yeah, I works with IE but not FF. How can I make it work with both IE and FF ?

Comment: It doesn't work in Safari either. [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/U0eQgF2PP7j0). I'm also wondering how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the head-tag with getElementsByTagName... like:

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
$(headID).append('<base target="_blank" />');
```

On a quick test this worked at least on chrome & firefox 3.6.