# How to append html to <head> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a Facebook open graph tag (based on dynamically generated content on the page) to the head of my html.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var stat = $('#random-message').text();
stat = jQuery.trim(stat);

//set facebook Open Graph description
$('head').append('<meta property="og:description" content="'+stat+'"/>');

  });
```

this by itself is working fine. [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrengy/HQMCz/4/)

When I combine it with a dynamically loaded Twitter script (below)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var stat = $('#random-message').text();
stat = jQuery.trim(stat);
//set tweet button data text
$('a.twitter-share-button').attr('data-text',stat);

//set facebook Open Graph description
$('head').append('<meta property="og:description" content="'+stat+'"/>');

//insert twitter API Script - problematic
$('#tweet-like').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>');

});
```

it chucks a wobbly. [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrengy/2jEXp/1/) In js fiddle, it inserts some special characters into the body, and none of the rest of the script (including inserting the meta tag) is working. Strange because the Twitter script "widgets.js" is working on my page, but the meta tag does not appear.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032630/append-html-to-head-with-jquery)

Comment: head is just another tag, append should not have trouble

Comment: May I ask why you need to append this after the page loads? When facebook initially looks for the meta tag in the head and it doesn't find it, it wont mater if you're loading it after that?

Comment: Confirm working on Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 10 (jQuery 1.5.1) :)

Comment: It's mainly for a like button, so for that purpose at least, it doesn't need to load until document ready.

Comment: Interesting - I got it working in a js fiddle as well, but for some reason, it's not happening on my page - more debugging to do, thanks...

Comment: what harm would it do if it was loaded in the head from the beginning?

Comment: no harm in loading it in the head from the start, but it's just simpler this way based on how I have started to build it already... I see, from Guffa's answer - I may have to do this via php instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facebook doesn't use the meta tags in the current page, it requests the page anew and parses it. As that parsing doesn't involve running any Javascript in the page, it won't add the meta tag to the data that is read.

To make the meta tag work it has to be present in the page from start, it can't be added using client script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34284383/470749 seems to agree that Open Graph tags changed client-side (via javascript) will not be parsed.