# Facebook Sharing Debugger scraping main page URL instead of given URL in Angular 6

Tags: angular, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

The Facebook Sharing Debugger tool is scraping the wrong page.

I have given a complete URL with slug (pointing to an individual page on my site) that I want it to share via facebook share button. Instead of scraping the page I want, it scrapes my site's main page .

I want it to scrape `https://example.com/slug`
Instead, it scrapes `https://example.com`

I have updated the meta tag of og:url using the following code below

```
this.meta.updateTag({
      property: 'og:url',
      content: 'https://example.com/'+this.slug
    });
```

And it is working fine ( by inspecting the current page ). But facebook open graph is scraping the main page of my site instead of updated `og:url`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Facebook Open Graph tags possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281862/dynamic-facebook-open-graph-tags-possible)

Comment: No it doesnt answer my question. The similar thing works for my main website but when it comes to subdomain it not working.

Comment: the main point is: you are trying to set dynamic og tags, which does not work, no matter if top level domain or subdomain. og tags must be available in the initial page source. you can use SSR or something like prerender.io for that. do you have a test url for us?

Comment: We are using SSR only. Here is the requested URL:
The URL it is scraping: http://iages.therightdoctors.com,
The URL we want to scrape: https://iages.therightdoctors.com/the-last-word/iages-2020-dr-ramananda-saikia-laparoscopic-cbd-exploration-using-bronchoscopy

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Shorturl as og:url, and it leads to the main URL. Use the correct permalink instead:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://iages.therightdoctors.com/the-last-word/iages-2020-dr-ramananda-saikia-laparoscopic-cbd-exploration-using-bronchoscopy">
```

**Important: Facebook ignores JavaScript, so you cannot set/update the tag on the client.**

Comment: But this 'og:url' needs to get updated for every other page as well then permalink keeps on changing as well.So that's why we have written meta.updateTag() to update 'og:url' . But Facebook is not scraping the updated URL instead it is scraping the index file url

Comment: i added something about that in my answer, to make it perfectly clear.

Comment: Then how should we proceed further? We have so many slugs , this is the meta tag in index.html.
 how should we set up permalink for differents urls.

Comment: the permalink HAS to be in the source of the page. SSR is one solution, prerender.io another one.