# Dynamically change og meta tag in Javascript project for social media sharing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am native android apps developer, am trying to develop a news web site using Firestore. I learned to develop web site from [friendlyeats-web](https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-web) I followed the same structure everything went well and development part is almost completed.

Users can share news url to social medias, While user sharing news web page in social media I need to show **title**, **description** and **image**. Every web page will have different news so I tried to change `og:title`, `og:description` dynamically using javascript but it's not worked in WhatsApp and Facebook.

**Here is my Javascript code:**

```
document.querySelector('meta[property="og:title"]').setAttribute("content", title);
document.querySelector('meta[property="og:description"]').setAttribute("content", desc);
```

I googled and many answers said to use `server side rendering` but I don't know how to integrate to this Javascript based project. Your suggestions and thoughts will be more helpful for me to overcome this issue thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try to do by creating a new element.

```
<script>
  var ogTitle = document.createElement('meta');
  ogTitle.setAttribute('property', 'og:title');
  ogTitle.content = title
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(ogTitle);
</script>
```

Comment: I will try and let you know, Thanks

Comment: It's added in html file but in Facebook sharing is not working.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34284383/9713119

Comment: did u clear your cache using Facebook debugger